# Getting nodes by attribute value in DomXML and PHP

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to select a specific node to edit its content and attributes later on, but I am not able to select a `notice` node (see the PHP code below).

**XML document**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<notices lastID="0001">
    <!--
    <notice id="0000" endDate="31-12-2025">
        Content of the notice.
    </notice>
    -->
    <notice id="0001" endDate="13-01-2013" active="1">
        One amazing notice.
    </notice>

</notices>
```

The `$id` value is "0001" (*string*).

**PHP**

```
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document = dom_import_simplexml($this->xml);

$notices= $document->getElementsByTagName('notice');
#var_dump($notices);

foreach($notices as $element)
{
    if($element->getAttribute('id') == $id)
    {
        $notice = $element;
        var_dump($notice); //Returns absolutely nothing (I guess the if returns false).
    }
}

$notice->removeAttribute("endDate");
$notice->setAttribute("endDate",$endDate);
```

Everytime I fall into the `if` statement, my `$notice` returns no value.
I tried with xpath query ( `//notice[@id="{$id}"]`) without any success.

To clarify, my problem would be `$element->getAttribute('id')` does not seem to work.

---

I also tried with **SimpleXML**:

**PHP**

```
$document = new DOMDocument;
$document = simplexml_import_dom($this->xml);

$notice = "";

foreach($document->notices->children() as $element)
{
    $attributes = $element->attributes();
    if($attributes['id'] == $id)
    {
        $notice= $element;
        var_dump($notice);
    }
}
$avis->removeAttribute("endDate");
$avis->setAttribute("endDate",$endDate);
```

SimpleXML gives me the following message: `Node no longer exists` on the following line:

`foreach($document->notices->children() as $element)`

Comment: Did you check that the XML document is loaded properly? Not sure if this is the answer or not but try to load your file with `DOMDocument::load()` and you don't need to create a new instance of it `DOMDocument`.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it.

**PHP**

```
$document = simplexml_import_dom($this->xml);
$notice = "";

$xpathResults = $document->xpath('//notice');


foreach($xpathResults as $element)
{
    $elementID = $element->id[0];
    $domXML = dom_import_simplexml($element);

    if((string) $noticeID == $id)
    {
        $notice = $domXML;

    }
}
```

Comment: You can do that with xpath directly. You probably need to find out *why* it didn't work for you, probably `$id` contained something different or your xpath expression was borked. Use variables, in case it does not work, you can var_dump those and see what is going on: http://eval.in/6307